# Redirecting to external Links in .net Form based Approach

Tags: c#, html, .net, web

How can I redirect to some external website by using a URL as a Command Argument?

I'm trying to redirect to facebook.com but it gives `http://localhost:58709/www.facebook.com%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20` in address bar.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{    
    Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You need the protocol in the link. You must be missing http(s)://

Comment: You are missing the HTTP in your URL try to [debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.facebook.com");
```